# Converting google map to pdf in php

Tags: php, google-maps, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF for generating PDF documents and i want to convert a google static image map into my pdf. How can i achieve this, some examples?

Comment: Please review the Terms of Service. What you're proposing would seem to violate the terms: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html


"(h) No Use of Static Maps API(s) outside a Web-Based Application (Except with a Link to Google Maps)." (section 10.1.1)  

"(a) No Unauthorized Copying, Modification, Creation of Derivative Works, or Display of the Content." (section 10.1.3)

Comment: I accomplished the task, but even if I embed the link into the pdf, i violate section 10.1.3, so thanks.

Comment: @andresf, nobody seem to care... ;-/ However, the terms continues with: 

"...unless:

(i) your platform does not have a web browser; or

(ii) if your platform does have a web browser, you provide a link that shows the location concerned either (x) in the Google Maps native application (if your platform has one); or (y) on the Google Maps website."

(I'm not sure I 100% understand this last one (ii) though... Link to some(!) relevant geo-position on the map?)

Comment: @andresf, BTW, and there's also that _"(Except with a Link to Google Maps)"_, already in (h), which you've quoted. I'm really confused now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try static google map to embed map in pdf. Static map generate image file which will easily added thorough document. I haven't tried but it should work...

For more detail see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: See my comment above.  While technically this may be viable, it still seems to violate the terms of service.

Comment: @andresf, +1 (here, too :) ) for pointing it out. However, see above: not necessarily. The terms do have a slightly undecipherable "except" clause, which suggests that if you provide a link to "reproduce" (?) the map, you are actually OK. Someone *really* should clarify that...

Answer (score 1):

Build the google static map link, docs can be found http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Use the writeHTML method of TCPDF to write the following:

```
<img src="http://yourgooglemapurl.com"/>
```